# Trying to move left element to right and vice versa using constraints. But it shrinks the main view on moving elements

Tags: xamarin.mac

I have one Main view inside that a inner View. This custom view has TextLines on left and Image View on Right. I am changing constraints to move image to left and text lines to right. but it shrinks the view and displays view of width just equal image.

```
NSLayoutConstraint primaryMainImageLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(primaryImage, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, showTextLinesAndMainIconsView, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1, 0);
NSLayoutConstraint showTextLinesTrailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(mainTextField1, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, showTextLinesAndMainIconsView, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1, 0);
NSLayoutConstraint primaryImageShowTextHorizontalSpacingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(mainTextField1, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, primaryImage, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1, 300);
private void SetGraphicWithTextLayout()
{
    this.View.AddConstraint(primaryMainImageLeadingConstraint);
    this.View.AddConstraint(showTextLinesTrailingConstraint);
 this.View.AddConstraint(primaryImageShowTextHorizontalSpacingConstraint);

}
```

Comment: Custom View mentioned is referring to inner view.
One more thing, When I navigate back to this screen the screen displays perfectly. Please suggest what I am doing wrong. Thanks